# XSL output displays as text instead of display as XML

Tags: xml, xslt

and also the indent does not work!

I need to generate an XML file from small files, so I tried using XSL to merge all files, but it does not work as expected.

When viewing "devices.xml" when all files are uploaded to a site:

- FireFox - displays as text
- InternetExplorer - displays as text
- Chrome - displays as text

and when I use "File | save as" -

- FireFox - saves the generated XML -   myRoot-device-input1- . . .
- InternetExplorer - saves the original XML - device_list-file . . .
- Chrome - saves the original XML - device_list-file . . .

When viewing "devices.xml" as local file:

- FireFox - displays as text
- InternetExplorer - "Access is denied. Error processing resource"
- Chrome - displays blank page ???

**My questions:**

1. Why do I see the generated XML as Text?
2. Can I force all browsers to save the generated XML and not the original XML?

**source files:**

devices.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="./mergedocs.xsl" ?>
<device_list> 
 <file name="./device1.xml" />
 <file name="./device2.xml" />
</device_list>
```

device1.xml

```
<d>
<i1 v="11" />
<i2 v="11" />
</d>
```

device2.xml

```
<d>
<i1 v="22" />
<i2 v="22" />
</d>
```

probes1.xml

```
<p name="probes1">
  <Item>"1 Name Pb1"</Item>
  <Item>"2 Name Pb1"</Item>
</p>
```

probes2.xml

```
<p name="probes2">
  <Item>"1 Name Pb2"</Item>
  <Item>"2 Name Pb2"</Item>
</p>
```

mergedocs.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:variable name="probes1" select="document('probes1.xml')" />
<xsl:variable name="probes2" select="document('probes2.xml')" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <myRoot> 
    <xsl:for-each select="/device_list/file">
      <device>
        <xsl:variable name="k" select="position()" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document(@name)/d" >
          <xsl:with-param name="strK" select="$k"/> 
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </device>     
    </xsl:for-each>
  </myRoot> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="d">
  <xsl:param name="strK" />    
  <xsl:apply-templates >
    <xsl:with-param name="strK" select="$strK"/> 
  </xsl:apply-templates >
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="i1">
 <xsl:param name="strK" />    
 <input1>
   <name><xsl:value-of select="$probes1//Item[position() = $strK]"/></name>
   <value><xsl:value-of select="@v" /></value>
 </input1>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="i2">
 <xsl:param name="strK" />    
 <input2>
   <name><xsl:value-of select="$probes2//Item[position() = $strK]"/></name>
   <value><xsl:value-of select="@v" /></value>
 </input2>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XSLT processors built in to the browser, especially when invoked using the xml-stylesheet PI, assume that you are generating HTML, and display the result as if it were HTML. This basically means ignoring all tags that have no meaning in HTML, so you just end up with the text.

From the description of what you are trying to achieve, it's not clear to me why you are trying to run this in the browser. You would be far better off using an XSLT processor you can run from the command line or from a GUI.

Comment: Thanks. Can I use local XSLT processor on XML files from the web? e.g. Use -
[msxsl.exe www.mySite.com\devices.xml .\mergedocs.xsl  -o .\output\merged.xml]
the same as -
[msxsl.exe .\devices.xml mergedocs.xsl  -o .\output\merged.xml]

Comment: Of course, once you are running XSLT on your local machine, you are no longer constrained to XSLT 1.0 or to an ancient processor like MSXML3.

Comment: I still has problems [maybe because i use an old version of msxsl.exe , now I try to find the latest version], I get [xslt code 0x800c0006, system error -2146697210 ] probably because it cannot locate the deviceN.xml files. these files must come from the server.

Comment: solved my problem using -
<xsl:variable name="device1_names" select="document('http://www.mySite.com/probes1.xml')" />
and not using -
<file name="./device1.xml" />